# Trying to rehabilitate an old PC, encountering RAID error

Tags: hard-drive, boot, raid, repair

I have a computer that I aim to turn into a server, but I am running into an error where I can't even reach the BIOS setup screen.

#### Summary.

Trying to boot PC, encounter error:

```
Detecting arrays ...
No disk reserved for RAID use, RAID disabled
```

And the computer hangs at this point.

#### Details.

- **CPU**: Unknown
- **Motherboard**: Dell TED-PP150 PWA Druid
- **Hard Drives**: 3x unknown contents

#### What I've tried.

- Of course I've tried powering it on, and I get stuck at the error. I also sometimes get a floppy disk error 40 (not sure why, there is no floppy drive on the system), but I can bypass this by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>.
- I tried seeing if other people have this problem and from what I found people suggested that the problem is with the hard drive. I do not know the state of the hard drives, nor do I have any way to fix them.
- Based on this, I unplugged the hard drive SATA cables and plugged in a Linux live USB to try and get something to boot, but even with the hard drives unplugged, I couldn't get past the RAID error.

#### What I would like.

My end goal is to get this system running Linux, and I do not care about the current contents of the hard drives. Any advice on how to get past this error or reset the computer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like it might be a CMOS battery issue. Funny feeling that if you changed the CMOS battery you could get into the BIOS and change something to get it to at least boot.

Comment: Ooo thanks that's something I didn't think about! I'll give it a try and report back.

Edit: Ordered some replacement batteries, should be here later today. Will update when they arrive.

Comment: Dell usually uses DEL, F2 or sometimes F10 to get into the bios. You need to try those keys BEFORE it goes into the RAID bios. That RAID bios you can also enter, usually by F4, Ctrl-A or Ctrl-S as soon as it displays a message on-screen.
You may have  to go into the RAID bios and remove the existing raid-set definition before it will boot.

Comment: So from what I see on the boot screen before the computer hangs, F2 is supposed to open the setup menu, and F12 is supposed to open the boot select menu. Neither of these opened before I run into the RAID issue though.

I just tried DEL and F10 as well, with no success. F4, Ctrl-A and Ctrl-S also seem to have no effect.

Comment: @Zico Like I said, CMOS battery might be the issue here. Wacky stuff as you describe is typically related to CMOS settings not working as expected due to the battery being dead or dying.

Comment: @giacomo1968 Just installed a new CMOS battery, no luck. Still having the exact same error. :(

Comment: Welp! Leave the question up here with these comments intact and wait to see if someone with more specific experience on a setup like this comes along to assist.

Comment: Yep. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have hardware raid? Is your OS on the RAID? The battery issue should help. Nothing like a fresh batt. :)

You can use a live USB to see if your system will boot.

Make sure the first boot device is USB stick or F12.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure if I have hardware raid, how can I check? The new battery didn't help :(. Live USB won't work because I can't get into boot settings.

Comment: Looks like I did have a hardware raid of some kind! https://www.siig.com/serial-ata-pci.html. When I removed it, I was able to book a Live USB. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Funny how the bot doesn't recognize that my thought provoking questions seems to have led to the cure. However, I am still struggling through my own RAID0 issues. And now, back to the index! :D